# Remove columns from df where one of 2 values has very few instances

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df where I noticed that in some columns there are 2 distinct values, however, there's very few occurrences for one of the values. For example, in column `col x` I have two values: 0 or 1. However, `value_counts()` showed me that only 2 rows have the value of 1. So I'd like to remove this column (not the row).

```
df["col x"].value_counts()
0.00000    26868
1.00000        2
Name: col x, dtype: int64
```

How can I remove columns from my dataframe where there are only 2 possible values, and one of them has a very small occurrece (say less than 0.1%)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably more elegant solutions, but this should do the trick:

```
check_max_pct = lambda x : x.value_counts().max()/x.value_counts().sum() < 0.998
df = df.loc[:, [check_max_pct(df[col]) for col in df.columns]]
```

The function checks whether the dominant value in a column makes up over 99.8% of all values (can be adjusted by changed the `0.998` value), so it should also extend to instances where there are more than two unique values in a column, but only a single value makes almost all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this code:

```
two_dist_vales_cols = df.loc[:, (df.nunique() == 2)].columns
to_drop = []
for col in two_dist_vales_cols:
    if (df[col].value_counts(ascending=True).iloc[0]) < 15:
        to_drop.append(col)
df.drop(columns=to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

First I find the columns where there are only 2 distinct values. Then loop through them, count the values and check the lowest one. If it's below a treshold, I add that column to the list of columns to be dropped, then drop them.